# Looking to take a hotspot that is shared and create my own hotspot that can be firewalled

Tags: wifi, vpn, firewalls, wireless

What is the best way to take a wireless hotspot that is owned by someone else, create my own hotspot or VLAN to be able to Firewall / Not allow my devices to view the other individuals' devices?

I am already using a VPN, but I want to be able to create my own hotspot from another hotspot and firewall it or create another VLAN. Is this recommended? What do you recommend? Is a VPN enough? Attempting to accomplish this is redundant? Or could it be an extra layer of security?

Comment: "take a wireless hotspot that is owned by someone else and create my own hotspot" -- I'm not sure what that means

Comment: I think OP wants to connect to a hotspot, firewall it, and share it on another wifi card.

Comment: Yes I am living in a house with many many people, I would like to take the public hotspot we are all using, create my own hotspot, and firewall it like stated above. Perhaps even place a VPN on my own hotspot for all my devices. Thanks. For understanding @ThoriumBR

Comment: you usually need a computer with two NICs to do this. adding a usb wifi card to a laptop should work. then you need NAT software or a proxy server.

Comment: If you use a VPN on your device, and every one does the same, you don't have to create a hotspot, or a firewall...

Comment: @dandavis not necessarily, one antena can multiplex, Windows has done it for years. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myHotspot key=Pass1234` and from here on you can add all the security you want withing the host (Windows) so... you should know your way from here on. Also, have in mind this is a virtual adapter.

Comment: Now what if my machines are Linux based, I do not use Windows @ Home. My machines would either be Linux or Mac OS X Based. I was able to create a second SSID, via Network-Manager on linux, but not able to pass on an internet connection. -> My SSID would keep saying No Internet Connection Present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am already using a VPN, but I want to be able to create my own
>   hotspot from another hotspot and firewall it or create another VLAN.
>   Is this recommended? What do you recommend? Is a VPN enough?
>   Attempting to accomplish this is redundant? Or could it be an extra
>   layer of security?

Oh my, this is not going to achieve what you think it will. If I understood correctly, there are some kind of a shared wifi hotspot, to which you wish to connect, then reshare the connection it provides via additional wifi hotspot created by you in order to elevate a security posture of your network, right? Well, there are no point in doing so, as all the traffic will still be visible to the original owner, and he can take his sweet time to decrypt it (if VPN are being used, or whatnot) by acting as man in the middle (say, acting as a proxy, forcing you to use the certificates he provided and so on)

Comment: Okay, I am not sure that the people I am living with are tech savvy enough to have a simple router provided by an ISP to connect via VPN, as I am using my own VPN as well, but what do you recommend if I want to create another subnet for my own machines, in order to hide them from any else on the network. I really want to create a "firewall" between my machines, and the machines my room mates use (aside from using software firewalls/my personal vpn) What again would you recommend, for best security practice. I do not want my machines to be shown via nmap.

Comment: Then it is not a hotspot but an Access Point. If you wish to separate your network from theirs, then the method you described will work. However, please understand, that it will not shield you if somebody with physical access to Access Point will change the default gateway (WAN gateway) and reroute the traffic to their own network for interception. So the answer to "will I protect my network" then yes (meaning intrusion protection). "Will I achieve 100% privacy?" the answer is Maybe.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, now I understand. My main plan was creating this new access point, routing my traffic through my own private VPN for Privacy/Setting up a firewall, , but what you are saying makes sense....so again thank you, for explaining this to me. The idea would be privacy, intrusion protection I am aware of, but what I want to do is perhaps stop man-in-the-middle attacks/hijacking sessions/make it much more hard in order to accomplish them.

Comment: I was reading your other questions, and I would advice to you actually get a separate WAN connection, be it 3G modem, line or whatever else to achieve your privacy.

Comment: Thank you again @Rashad, for your advice, but would this not run up a mega bill? as typical 3g modems, charge by mb's?

Comment: You can have a prepaid traffic, or can use something else.